# Sum by model method and inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have 3 models, User, Applicant and ApplicantCommission.

```
user has_many applicants 
applicant has many applicant_commissions
```

I would like to return a **sum** of the applicant_commission instance method to the *parenting models*. So `@user.getTotalCommission` will return the sum of all applicant_commissions over every applicant. `@applicant.getTotalCommission` would return every commission belonging to that applicant, and `@applicant_commission.getTotalCommission` would return the total value for just one commission type.

In ApplicantCommission.rb I have a instance method:

```
   # Returns the full amount of commission that the post has earned from this commission group.
  def getTotalCommission
    #Does some calculations
   return number_with_precision(total.round(2), :precision => 2)
  end
```

Applicant.rb

```
def getTotalCommission
  self.applicant_commissions.to_a.sum(&:getTotalCommission)
end
```

User.rb

```
def getTotalCommission
  self.applicants.to_a.sum(&:getTotalCommission)
end
```

Currently, if I have 2 applicant commissions, one 12.20 and another 10.00, I get 12.2010.00. The desired output would be 22.20.

It's supposed to be *based* around simple inheritance.. so perhaps I'm going down the wrong route completely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your use of `number_with_precision` which is a helper method to use in views which formats your number so that it can be displayed. It returns a string. Rails also provides the [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) method which adds all the things in the array together.

Essentially you're getting an array `["12.20", "10.00"]` and then it is getting "summed" by doing `"12.20" + "10.00"`

I would try and keep your total commission as a number as long as possible and only format it using `number_with_precision` when you are displaying it.

If your `getTotalCommission` method in `ApplicantComission` is just:

```
def getTotalCommission
  total.round(2)
end
```

then your summing code will work as expecting.

P.S. I'd question whether you even need to round it at that point too - you may only need to round it when you output the value

P.P.S. You're not actually doing inheritance which is when different classes inherit from each other. You're methods both have the same interface because they both have a `getTotalCommission` method but it is not through inheritance.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't considered this to be my issue!

Comment: Yeh, I realise I'm not actually using inheritance. Honestly, I'm not sure how I could do that properly, although I feel like I should be.

Comment: You look like you're coming from a more strongly typed language given your method naming (typically ruby would use `get_total_commission`). Because both your classes have the `getTotalCommission` method they kind of already have the same interface (they quack like something that implements `getTotalCommission`) so their instances could both be passed to something expecting an object that has `getTotalComission` - it just all happens without your having to explicitly define them as being the same kind of thing so there's no real need for explicit inheritance (at the moment :) )

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in the `getTotalCommission` method, just try this:

```
def getTotalCommission
  # becase number_with_precision returns string.
  number_with_precision(total.round(2), :precision => 2).to_f
end
```

I hope it will help.

You might need to modify `User#getTotalCommission`

```
def getTotalCommission
  number_with_precision(applicants.to_a.sum(&:getTotalCommission), precision: 2).to_f
end
```